# MobX Gulp error by using Annotations (Decorators)

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have this basic React (MobX) store. Gulp runs normally but I still get error in browser (*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined*). I tested everything and if I don't add the @observable then it works. In the generated *js* file the problem occurs at the same place where the annotation would be interpreted.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {autorun, observable, computed} from "mobx";

class Store {
  @observable elements = [];

  constructor() {
    this.elements = [];
  }

  clickElement(id) {
    if (this.elements.length > 1) {
        for (var i=0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
            this.elements[i].clicked = false;
            if (this.elements[i].id == id) {
                this.elements[i].clicked = true;
            }
        }
    }
  }

  getSelectedIndex() {
    for (var i=0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
        if (this.elements[i].clicked) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
  }
}

var store = new Store();
export default Store;

autorun(() => { console.log(store.elements) })
```

Gulp task extract:

```
gulp.task('build:react', function () {
var paths = {
    src: path.join(config.baseDir, 'my.jsx'),
    dest: path.join(config.baseDir, 'scripts')
};
gulp.src(paths.src)
    .pipe(webpackStr({
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: ['', '/\.js?$/', '/\.jsx?$/'],
                    loader: 'babel',
                    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                    query: {
                        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
                        plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy']
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }))
    .pipe(concat('react.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(pathsShop.dest));
});
```

Generated code:

```
var _class, _desc, _value, _init;

var _react = __webpack_require__(2);

var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);

var _mobx = __webpack_require__(399);



var DetailPageStore = (_class = function () {

    function DetailPageStore() {
        _classCallCheck(this, DetailPageStore);

        this.elements = _init.apply(this);
    }
```

Comment: Where's the generated js code?

Comment: Made an update but I don't think this will help muc.